# Either this is not a SignalR endpoint or there is a proxy blocking the connection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr

I have this SignalR connection in my project which works fine unless the url changes from root.
For example: `localhost:5001/notifications` works fine but when the url is changed during navigation let's say `https://localhost:5001/Identity/Account/Manage` signalR connection fails and in the browser console it shows the SignalR connection url mapped to the new url as `https://localhost:5001/Identity/Account/Manage/notificationHub/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1`

**Hub Class**

```cs
public class NotificationHub : Hub { }
```

**notification.js**

```js
var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
  .withUrl('/notificationHub')
  .build()

connection.on('ReceiveNotification', function (result, count) {
  console.log('Result', result) 
})

connection
  .start()
  .then(function () {
    //do something
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    console.error(err.toString())
  })
```

**Startup.cs**

```cs
app.UseEndpoints(ep =>
{
    ep.MapHub<NotificationHub>("/notificationHub");
});
```

**Full browser console log**

```
Normalizing 'notificationHub' to 'https://localhost:5001/Identity/Account/notificationHub'
signalr.js:447 [2024-01-29T13:55:39.520Z] Error: Failed to start the connection: Error: Failed to complete negotiation with the server: Error: : Status code '404' Either this is not a SignalR endpoint or there is a proxy blocking the connection.
log @ signalr.js:447
notification.js:66 Error: Failed to complete negotiation with the server: Error: : Status code '404' Either this is not a SignalR endpoint or there is a proxy blocking the connection.
```

Comment: You have a Route issue.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#how-to-register-signalr-middleware

Comment: HubConnectionBuilder needs the full url

Comment: @jdweng I am using dotnet core

Comment: @GHDevOps how do I do that?

Comment: Dotnet and GHdevOps will not affect the SignalR connection.  You are failing because the user does not have the permission to access the route.  You are making a HTTP(s) connection and the user credentials are passed from client to server.  These credentials are being blocked do to the permission of the Route in the server.

Comment: @jdweng what makes you think this is a permissions issue?

Comment: @mason : Status Code 404.

Comment: @jdweng And what makes you think that a 404 is a permissions issue?

Comment: @mason : The OP says "works fine unless the url changes from root" which eliminates every other reason for a HTTP 404 error provided the Route Exists.

Comment: @jdweng A 404 error is pretty clearly a route issue, rather than a permissions issue. Unless someone customized the app to return 404 instead of 401 or 403 when unauthenticated or unauthorized. Making the leap to it being a permission issue rather than a simple path problem doesn't seem correct.

Answer (score -1):

To avoid this behavior you could try below code:

```
var baseUrl = window.location.origin;

var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl(baseUrl + '/notificationHub')
    .build();
```

Comment: You code is using Websockets.  OP has not indicated that he is using Websockets.

Comment: @jdweng. No, that's SignalR, which uses whatever transport protocol it can to establish a connection.